# R Panel Data: Difference between Pooling OLS and Fixed Effect with only "individual" effect

Tags: r, time-series, panel-data, fixed-effects-model, pooling

I just estimated my paneldata with Pooled OLS or with the Fixed Effect approach. When using FE with the effect="individual" I get a higher adjusted R^2 than using FE with effect="twoways". So I would prefer the first FE model, of course considering also my significance of the coefficients. But now I am asking, if it makes a real difference between using POLS or this FE with "individual-effect"? Because I avoid to capture the effects that are specific to time period but constant over panel units.

Maybe someone can help.. I know the difference in the technique of POLS and FE as an de-meaned model.. but maybe someone can answer in this specific case..

An extra information is also that my panel data consists of prices, which differ each month

Thank you!!